# Sqlbulkcopy using ASP works in iis6 but fails in iis7

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, sqlbulkcopy, records

I am able to get sqlbulkcopy working well on iis6(testing server) and iis7(live server) but when uploading the data in iis7, the rows are cut off. It only imports ~190,000 out of 250000 in iis7. In iis 6 using the same code/page it loads all 250000 records without issues. Also both servers are updating the same SQL DB.

I have searched all over for a solution. Any help is much appreciated.

```
    Sub UpdateData()

    Dim sSQLTable As String = "Table1"
    Dim sExcelFileName As String = savePath
    Dim sWorkbook() As String = GetExcelSheetNames(sExcelFileName)

    'Create our connection strings
    Dim sExcelConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & sExcelFileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"""

    'Execute a query to erase any previous data from our destination table
    Dim sClearSQL = "DELETE FROM " & sSQLTable
    Dim SqlConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConnString)
    Dim SqlCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sClearSQL, SqlConn)
    SqlConn.Open()
    SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    SqlConn.Close()

    'Series of commands to bulk copy data from the excel file into our SQL table
    Dim OleDbConn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(sExcelConnectionString)
    OleDbConn.Open()

    Dim OleDbCmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(("SELECT * FROM [" & sWorkbook(0) & "]"), OleDbConn)
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = OleDbCmd.ExecuteReader()
    Dim bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(ConnString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction)
    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 2000
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = sSQLTable
    'DEMO bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Excel", "SQL")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Material", "Material")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Plnt", "Plant")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("SLoc", "SLoc")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("S", "S")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Batch", "Batch")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Special Stock Number", "SpecialStockNumber")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Material Description", "MatDesc")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Typ", "Type")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("StorageBin", "StorageBin")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Available stock", "AvailStock")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("BUn", "BUn")
    'bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("GR Date", "GRDate")
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr)
    OleDbConn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions?
Is the live server further away (perhaps timeout-related)?
Is there anything relevant in event viewer?

Comment: the DB sits on the live server. One and the same. Also I get NO errors. It simply runs and stops at a certain record count. I use the same excel file for both tests.

Comment: You mentioned that the IIS7 box stops after approximately 190,000 rows. Is the exact row count always the same on the IIS7 server, or does it vary between runs?

Comment: And since SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer is void, it could also be that the OleDbDataReader is not returning all the rows. Hmmm...what about the app pool settings (classic or integrated)? And you double-checked event viewer?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the timeout at all? Or does the bulk insert finish long before the timeout?

Comment: Every run give me the exact recordcount. I have played with different timeouts and batchsize options. What throws me off is that the script works well in iis6. Confirming that I dont see any events popup in the event viewer under Application, System or Webserver view.

Comment: A couple questions:  1) Do you have the same version of Office installed on each server (or the same version of the Microsoft Access Database Engine redistributable?)  2) Are both the servers 64-bit (or 32-bit?)  3) What version of Excel was used to create the source file?

Comment: The default app pool is set to integrated.

Comment: The iis6 is on my XP laptop. IIS7 is on win2008 64bit server.Both have the same version of Office. But I had to install the 32bit MADE. After your comment I re-saved the file, by copy pasting the data to fresh Excel file in the same Office 2010 version. Now it gives me a different count of records but close to 190,000.

Comment: What is the size of your Excel file on disk?

Comment: Size of excel file is 1.49MB, .xlsx file

Comment: I thought maybe it was some sort of memory issue, but that's a relatively small file. My guess is that on the production server, the data reader isn't reading all the rows from the Excel file. My suggestion would be to remove OleDb from the equation, and use something like [ExcelDataReader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com). This will read the Excel file using OpenXML instead of using the OleDb. As a bonus, this approach doesn't require you to install any Office/ACE components on your web server.

Comment: Andy, thank you for your time and help.. Let me give it a shot. Will update soon with results.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Andy for the ExcelDataReader tip!

Got it to work with [ExcelDataReader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/). Looks like it was a memory issue with OleDB. Posting my code in case it will help others in future.

```
    Sub updateData()
    Dim sSQLTable As String = "Table1"

    'Execute a query to erase any previous data from our destination table
    Dim sClearSQL = "DELETE FROM " & sSQLTable
    Dim SqlConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConnString)
    Dim SqlCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sClearSQL, SqlConn)
    SqlConn.Open()
    SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    SqlConn.Close()


    Dim stream As FileStream = File.Open(savePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

    '1. Reading from a binary Excel file ('97-2003 format; *.xls)
    'Dim excelReader As IExcelDataReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream)

    '2. Reading from a OpenXml Excel file (2007 format; *.xlsx)
    Dim excelReader As IExcelDataReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream)

    '3. DataSet - The result of each spreadsheet will be created in the result.Tables
    'Dim ds As DataSet = excelReader.AsDataSet()

     '4. DataSet - Create column names from first row
    excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = True
    Dim ds As DataSet = excelReader.AsDataSet()
    Dim sourceData As New DataTable()
    sourceData = ds.Tables(0)

    ''5. Data Reader methods
    'Using destinationConnection As New SqlConnection(ConnString)
    ' open the connection

    'destinationConnection.Open()
    'Using bulkCopy As New SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection.ConnectionString)

    ' column mappings
    Dim bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(ConnString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction)
    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 2000
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = sSQLTable

    'DEMO bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Excel", "SQL")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Material", "Material")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Plnt", "Plant")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("SLoc", "SLoc")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("S", "S")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Batch", "Batch")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Special Stock Number", "SpecialStockNumber")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Material Description", "MatDesc")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Typ", "Type")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("StorageBin", "StorageBin")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Available stock", "AvailStock")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("BUn", "BUn")
    'bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("GR Date", "GRDate")

    'bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = sSQLTable
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(sourceData)

    '6. Free resources (IExcelDataReader is IDisposable)
    excelReader.Close()
End Sub
```